# Parse query synchronous and asynchronous error

Tags: ios, parsing, swift

Coding with iOS in swift and i'm using parse. I need to do a query to retrieve 1 object with his ID.
The problem is my query is successful when I make a query to find several objects but unccessful when I make a query to find 1 object :

This code works :

```
var queryEvent = PFQuery(className: "Event")
queryEvent.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: objectId)
    queryEvent.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            println("Successfully retrieved the object.")

        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            println("error: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

This code doesn't work:

```
var queryEvent = PFQuery(className: "Event")
queryEvent.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(objectId, block: { (object: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if object != nil {
            println("The getFirstObject request failed.")
            println(error) //contain nil
        } else {
            // The find succeeded.
            println("Successfully retrieved the object.")
        }
    })
```

So I want to use the method getObjectInBackgroundWithId because it is more appropriate but I don't know why it failed. Thanks

EDIT: Here is the code example from Parse I was following.

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"GameScore")
query.whereKey("playerEmail", equalTo:"dstemkoski@example.com")
query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock {
     (object: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
      if object != nil {
          NSLog("The getFirstObject request failed.")
      } else {
          // The find succeeded.
          NSLog("Successfully retrieved the object.")
      }
 }
```

Solution is in the comments below. thank you

Comment: `if object != nil` mean was ok…. but you: ` println("The getFirstObject request failed.”)`

Comment: Ok thanks a lot it works now, I was following the Parse example.